# Dual boot windows 11 and debian 11

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

[image: boot bios][image]

I'm trying to dual install Windows 11 and Debian (I have already installed Windows). I'm unfamiliar with disk partitions in general and don't know anything about Debian.

I've already tried to install Debian, but something went wrong and I couldn't boot it (there was no GRUB). So, I created a live USB stick and now trying to replace the old unbootable Debian with a new one. Is everything okay with what I'm going to do?

I tried to download boot repair but there were errors.

I'm worried about

```
Set up fat32 partition /dev/nvme0n1 with mount point /boot/efi%4
```

It looks like it's Windows boot manager, isn't? I don't want to make my Windows unbootable. Please help!

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS? Debian could already be there, you just need to set it by default. With EFI all operating systems use the same system boot partition, called the System EFI partition. I'm just confused to see `%4`, otherwise it looks alright.

Comment: Yes, and there wasn't debian. Only windows

Comment: Using live debian I can even access to disk part with that debian, and I know it's here. Using windows I can't do this. I thought if I would try to install grub everything gonna be ok. But, firstly, I've tried to install boot repair and there was problem with key. I installed key, but there still was a problem and I decided it would be much easier to reinstall it

Comment: I've attached a picture of bios

Comment: What happens if you press Enter on Windows Boot Manager?

Comment: I can press only F5 or F6 to move it down/up (when I have my live usb inserted I press F6, move up Linux, then exit saving changes and live debian starts)

Comment: Have you installed Debian again? Did it install GRUB successfully?

Comment: I haven't yet. Backuping my windows (I have errors even here) and then I will try to. Is there going to be any problems with that System EFI partition %4?

Comment: I don't know. I've tried to install Debian using their network installation image and I saw a different screen than what you're seeing. There was no mention of %4 anywhere.